# Baggage restrictions while travelling by connecting flights

Tags: air-travel, usa, luggage, american-airlines, qatar-airways

On Qatar airways it mentions that for business class a passenger is allowed a checked bag up to 32 kgs for business class and 23 kgs for economy. My tickets are booked for business class but I could not find any information specific for business class for American Airlines, which will be a connecting flight from port of entry in USA.

So if I pack a bag which weighs 25 kgs will I have to shell out extra fare for connecting flight i.e American Airlines ?

Also everywhere it mentions that the checkin bag should not be more than 158 cms in total (length + width + height) but is there any specific l, w, h for check in bag too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take up to three bags, each weighing to 32 kg, for free on every flight on this journey.

AA allows business class customers to take up to three bags for free, at 32 kg each.

1st, 2nd, and 3rd bag fees are waived for business class customers: https://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/baggage/checked-baggage.jsp

Overweight bag fee is waived for business class customers, up to 32 kg: https://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/baggage/oversize-overweight.jsp

US [federal regulations](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/399.87) require that you will have a consistent baggage allowance throughout your journey if the journey starts or ends in the United States. Therefore this allowance will be applied throughout your journey including onto Qatar Airways.

In practise, AA takes the most generous allowance that would apply at any point, and applies that throughout the ticket.

If you hold Emerald status with any oneworld airline, you will also get a fourth bag for free.

If any other carrier on this journey would give you an even more generous allowance, then the more generous allowance will apply.